# Polymorphic Vector storage for in-memory column store type of task

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

"My brain is about to explode" tells me ghc and the feeling is mutual.

There's an aggregation function that works as a charm on polymorphic vectors (in-memory column store context) - takes 2 vectors and groups by unique values of the 1st one while applying function f to values of the 2nd. So, similar to SQL GROUP BY or mongo aggregation. Examples:

```
\> groupColumns creg (+) cint
fromList [("EMEA",345),("NA",681),("RoW",988)]

\> groupColumns cint (*) cdouble
fromList [(1,13.0),(2,46.0),(4,16.0),(23,5359.0),(24,528.0),(234,5475.599999999999),(43,18619.0),(12,14.399999999999999),(412,1697.44),(252,-6350.4)]
```

Relevant code:

```
groupColumns :: (Eq k, G.Vector v k, G.Vector v2 a, Hashable k) =>
 v k -> (a -> a -> a) -> v2 a -> Map.HashMap k a
groupColumns xxs f yys = ...

cint :: U.Vector Int64
cint = U.fromList [1,2,43,234,23,412,24,12,4,252,1,2,43,234,23,412,24,12,4,252]

cdouble :: U.Vector Double
cdouble = U.fromList [13,23,433,23.4,233,4.12,22,1.2,4,-25.2, 1,2,43,234,23,412,24,12,4,252]

creg :: V.Vector Text
creg = V.fromList ["EMEA", "NA", "EMEA", "RoW", "NA", "RoW", "EMEA", "EMEA", "NA", "RoW", "EMEA", "NA", "RoW", "NA", "RoW", "NA", "RoW", "EMEA", "NA", "EMEA"]
```

The problem arises when I want to parse a user's input and run an aggregation function built dynamically. Let's say there's a source data table of `"Region" : Text, "Revenue" : Int, "Country" : Text, "Booking Date" : Int`. A user may want to do (pseudocode): 1) `groupby "Region", "Country" sum "Revenue"` or 2) `groupby "Country", "Booking Date" sum "Revenue"` etc etc. The issue is that "Region" and "Country" vectors are `V.Vector Text` while "Booking Date" and "Revenue" are `U.Vector Int64` - so I can't store them in one Hashtable or List and do an obvious thing: get abstract (Vector a) from this one Hashtable or List, pass them to `groupColumns` function (which already perfectly supports polymorphic vectors!!!) and get a result. I don't care about specific type here for groupColumns, I only care that whatever I'm passing supports Vector interface (by being part of the type family).

So, it boils down to: **I need some sort of Storage type that 1) given `Text` (name of the vector) 2) gives back `U.Vector a` or `V.Vector b` without explicit type signature**. In the ideal world it'd be just one line call: `groupColumns (extractVec col1 cms) func (extractVec col2 cms)`, where `col1` and `col2` is Text parsed from user input and `func` is a function dynamically set from parsed user input.

In the real world I tried:

1) heterogenous tricks (of the `Data HV where HV :: (Vector v a) => v a -> HV` sort) but there both mine and ghc brains start to explode because various type variables escape their scope (e.g., in the f function that is passed to groupColumns) - even though getting `(HV U.Vector Int64)` from `[(Text, HV a)]` is straightforward.

2) Typed vector storage, like this:

```
data ColumnMemoryStore = ColumnMemoryStore {
    intCols :: Map.HashMap Text (U.Vector Int64),
    doubleCols :: Map.HashMap Text (U.Vector Double),
    textCols :: Map.HashMap Text (V.Vector Text),
    typeSchema :: Map.HashMap Text SupportedTypes -- helper map from column names to their types

}
```

with polymorphic `extractVector` function, so I can do `extractVector name cms :: U.Vector Int64` - and it automagically returns U.Vector Int64 from the intCols and respectively for others. Here, the problem is that after parsing user input I have to analyze what is the Type of the vectors he wants to aggregate by (by consulting `typeSchema`) and give corresponding type signatures to `extractVector` calls - which turns into absolutely, terrifyingly ugly spaghetti of `case` statements that makes me want to write everything in C as it will be 5x shorter. Here's a sample:

```
let t1 = checkColType' colname (cms gs)
            case t1 of
                PText -> let col = extractVec colname (cms gs) :: V.Vector T.Text
                             result = groupColumns col (+) aggCol
                         in outputStrLn $ show result
                PInt -> let col = extractVec colname (cms gs) :: U.Vector Int64
                            result = groupColumns col (+) aggCol
                        in outputStrLn $ show result
```

etc etc etc. This compiles and works but it's ugly, non-functional and boilerplate. I mean, the ONLY reason for doing this is the need to specify return type of `extractVec` explicitly while *then* it's *never* used by `groupColumns`, which simply expects anything that's `Vector v a`! There has to be a way around it...

3) Should I even think about Data.Reflection or something similar but no less scary? Template Haskell?

I am sorry for a long description, but I spent tons of time researching and feel like completely stuck - which probably (hopefully) means I'm missing something pretty obvious (like not enough abstraction levels) and those of you who think in Haskell can at least point me to the correct approach of solving this issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your problem is one of fundamental design - `extractVec` takes a string but you want it to return the correct typed vector. There is no way it could expose which type of vector it returned to the outside world. You could write a function of type e.g. `Text -> ColumnMemoryStore -> (forall k v . (G.Vector k v, Eq v, Hashable v, Show v) => k v -> r) -> r`, but this only allows you to know the output is *some* vector type, not which particular type it is (i.e. the only things you can know about the ouput are those which are true for all outputs). In short you are asking for dependent types.

Comment: @user2407038 - thank you, started reading on dependent types and now wishing Idris was production ready :) However, my problem is also kind of the opposite - yes, dependent types would solve it, but maybe there's a proper way to design this in haskell keeping in mind that groupColumns function doesn't care what exact vector I'm passing to it, only that it's a vector - so, kind of what you suggest with the function above. Will look into it with some typeclass combinations, maybe something good will come out of it.

Comment: `groupColumns` *does* care about what exact type of vector it is, because it takes a function of type `a -> a -> a`. For example how could you write `groupColumns (extractVec col1 cms) (+) (extractVec col2 cms)`? What if one of the columns contains `Text` values? If `col1 :: Text` then you really need dependent types, no matter how you encode the table. OTOH, if you encode the schema at the type level, you can have column selectors and grouping expressions which "know about" types.

Comment: (+) is only applied to col2 values, and is being grouped by col1 values. So, col1 values can be whatever - main thing is that it's Hashable - while col2 values have to be able to be applied by (a->a->a). But your point stands regardless. Encoding schema at the type level works when you know the schema in advance, but when you are trying to implement something database-related where schema should be defined dynamically, it doesn't really help...

Comment: If your schema can truly vary at runtime, you'll probably be best off with `Typeable`. E.g. `data SomeVec = forall v a . (Typeable v, Typeable a) => SomeVec (v a)` gives you the "shape" of the vector at the type level (which is always the same) but hides all the type information. You don't need multiple maps then - just `HashMap Text SomeVec`. You don't even need a `HashMap Text SupportedTypes`, since `SomeVec` stores a representation of the type anyways.

Comment: @user2407038 - thank you for all the ideas, I played around with different options, made progress and then got stuck again - would you mind looking at the follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138376/rankntypes-and-existentials-cant-figure-out-one-final-step)? Thanks a bunch!