# RankNTypes and Existentials - can't figure out one final step

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

This is a continuation of the previous 2 questions on this topic, getting close but still one final step eludes me. Experts in RankNTypes and other advanced type programming in Haskell, really need your help! :)

There's a family of functions that can do pretty generic map-reduce on column data represented as Vectors, here's the simplest one that takes 2 vectors, groups by unique values of the 1st and runs various aggregation functions on the 2nd:

```
groupColumnsG1A1 ::
 (Eq k, G.Vector v k, G.Vector v2 r, Hashable k) =>
   v k -> (v1 -> v1 -> v1) -> (r -> v1) -> v2 r -> Map.HashMap k v1
groupColumnsG1A1 xxs f g yys = G.ifoldl' (\ !acc i x -> Map.insertWith f x (g $ yys G.! i) acc) Map.empty xxs
```

Given 2 sample vectors, boxed `V.Vector Text` `creg` and `U.Vector Int64` `cint` we can do a bunch of cool polymorphic stuff:

```
\> groupColumnsG1A1 creg (+) id cint
fromList [("EMEA",345),("NA",681),("RoW",988)]
-- ^ group and sum values in cint

\> groupColumnsG1A1 creg (+) (const 1) cint
fromList [("EMEA",7),("NA",7),("RoW",6)]
-- ^ group and count values in cint

> groupColumnsG1A1 creg (++) (:[]) cint
fromList [("EMEA",[252,12,1,12,24,43,1]),("NA",[4,412,234,2,4,23,2]),("RoW",[24,23,43,252,412,234])]
-- ^ group and put all cint values in lists
```

So far, all good and groovy - and important to note that this set of functions works with ALL kinds of Vectors we can feed it - Vector Text, U.Vector Double, U.Vector Int etc etc. Now, if you recall from [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112633/polymorphic-vector-storage-for-in-memory-column-store-type-of-task) the problem is that now on top of this pure functional goodies we have to interact with users, parse her queries and build calls to pure groupColumnsGnAm dynamically. After some helpful ideas given, I'm now trying to have one type that hides all the various Vectors in the system so that they can be stored in 1 HashMap and we can get them from there based on user's input:

```
data GenericVector where
GenericVector :: (Show a, Eq a, Hashable a, Vector v a, Show (v a)) => v a -> GenericVector
```

... and then build calls to our pure function like so - same as above but passing GenericVectors instead of specific vectors:

```
groupColumnsG1A1Gen :: forall v1. Show v1 => 
                   GenericVector -> 
                   (v1 -> v1 -> v1) -> 
                   (forall r. (r -> v1)) -> 
                   GenericVector -> IO ()
groupColumnsG1A1Gen (GenericVector x) f g (GenericVector y) = 
    do let res = groupColumnsG1A1 x f g y
       putStrLn $ show res
```

All this function does is pattern matches and unwraps our Vectors from `GenericVector` and calls corresponding pure function. **Now, here comes the problem.** As you can see, **type signature of this function follows `groupColumnsG1A1` with regards to `f` and `g`, so I'd assume it should exhibit all the same flexibility, but it does not work without some `RankNTypes` magic.** The above is as far as I could get, and the function works for counting example (`greg` and `gint` are `GenericVectors` hiding `creg` and `cint`):

```
\> groupColumnsG1A1Gen  greg (+) (const 1) gint
fromList [("EMEA",7),("NA",7),("RoW",6)]
```

But it fails miserably for both sum and list-building examples, here's the error for sum:

```
\> groupColumnsG1A1Gen  greg (+) id gint


Couldn't match type ‘r’ with ‘Integer’
  ‘r’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      a type expected by the context: r -> Integer at <interactive>:266:1
Expected type: r -> Integer
  Actual type: Integer -> Integer
In the third argument of ‘groupColumnsG1A1Gen’, namely ‘id’
In the expression: groupColumnsG1A1Gen greg (+) id gint
```

So, it doesn't like `id` here - but it accepts it perfectly in the pure function case, with the same signature `(r->v1)` (apart from RankN stuff, but without it doesn't even compile).

This makes me hope I'm on the right road, but my RankN fluency is nowhere near what it needs to be to figure correct qualifications by myself, so any help is much appreciated - **what should the type signature be to support at least the same 3 cases - `(+) id`, `(+) (const 1)`, `(++) (:[])`?** Maybe it's not just RankNTypes, but I need some typeclass or functional dependency here?

Thanks a lot! I commit to writing a tutorial based on this highly educational experience to give back to the community...

PS Here's the error for the list building case for full picture:

```
> groupColumnsG1A1Gen  greg (++) (:[]) gint

Couldn't match type ‘r’ with ‘()’
  ‘r’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      a type expected by the context: r -> [()] at <interactive>:268:1
Expected type: r -> [()]
  Actual type: r -> [r]
In the third argument of ‘groupColumnsG1A1Gen’, namely ‘(: [])’
In the expression: groupColumnsG1A1Gen greg (++) (: []) gint
```

Comment: The type `forall r. (r -> v1)` is inhabited only by functions of the form `const x` for some `x : v1`. It is not the same as the type `forall a . a -> a`. It still isn't clear what the actual problem is.. the code as given simply *doesn't make sense* - you are trying to pull type information from thin air. Have you tried using Typeable? At least, can you give an example of the whole "interact with users, parse her queries and build calls to pure groupColumnsGnAm dynamically" process, and how this desired function would fit into it?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to mimic mongo aggregation over in-memory column data storage, where columns are represented as unboxed Num vectors and boxed Text vectors. The issue is that Schema is not known at compile time, but is loaded from the filesystem (database). The user can enter queries like: "groupby "region", "year" aggregate sum "revenue", count "account" - system should be able to parse it, get corresponding vectors from memory and pass them to groupColumnsGnAm functions, which don't care what kind of vectors those are as example above shows.

Comment: I tried working with Dynamic but casting back requires explicit typing just as with custom "GenericVector" class. I looked into your suggested Typeable approach but didn't figure out how to do proper casting using it. I don't know, I'm starting to think it's just not the problem domain to be addressed by Haskell efficiently. HList is probably closest to this, but somewhat orthogonal. It's basically very simplified SQL if you like, but in the middle between inefficient "treat every cell as string" approach and safe but rigid fully typeable for which we need to know schema at compile time.

Comment: Here, it's optimized for speed for numeric vectors and allows some flexibility with remaining Text columns. Function groupColumnsG1A1 works fine with Vector Text f g Vector Int as well as Vector Int f g Vector Text and all kinds of other combinations - but I need to pass Vectors with explicit typing. I can't build explicit typing based on user's input (or I can but it's a crazy "case" tree). That's the dilemma. Sorry if it's unclear, I really tried :)

Comment: If the goal is to parse user queries, then you should design a language for user queries, not try to use general functions. Then start from the top, not from the bottom (you are mired in implementation details.. think about high-level design first). Write a function `runQuery :: UserQuery -> Table -> Table`.

Comment: Lots of people hook Haskell up to databases.